# How to subtract a property value from a list on a condition

Tags: c#, list, select, subtraction

In my C# application, I need to subtract a property value from a huge list (HoList? Right now i do this, not sure i so it right?

```
int value1 =2;
HoList.Select(r => r.Count - value1).ToList();
```

Comment: yes. if you want to say subtract value from property  "count" for each item, yes you are doing right.

Comment: yes, but it is not working?

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII solution is correct, if you wanted to subtract the value and replace it with the old value.

Comment: @AAAA - the code is wrong, it is discarding the result. Select will not modify the list in place, rather it returns a new, transformed list

Comment: By the way, it would have been easier for everyone if you had shown the type that HoList collects (i.e., assuming that `HoList` is a `List<T>`, what does the class `T` look like), and had described more clearly what you expected to get after your work was finished.  Your code above is correct, in some sense - It creates a new list of integers, and then throws the result away.  However, since we don't really know what you want, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Why not just: `foreach(var item in HoList) item.Count -= value1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question you're taking `HoList` which is some type with a property `Count`.  I can see that by looking at the `Select` statement.

When you call `Select` you are choosing what you want to return and in your example you're returning `Count - value1`.  This is most likely an `int` result.  `Select` is just returning an `IEnumerable<int>` and then `ToList()` is turning that `IEnumerable<int>` to a `List<int>`.  You're also not assigning that list to anything.

If you want to alter the original list you can do something like this:

```
HoList.ForEach(r => r.Count -= value1);
```

If it's a large list you can utilize parallelism for something like this also:

```
HoList.AsParallel().ForAll(r => r.Count -= value1);
```

Answer (score -1):

using you existing code the correction is this

```
int value1 =2;
HoList = HoList.Select(r => r.Count - value1).ToList();
```

or if you need to keep the original

```
int value1 =2;
var newList = HoList.Select(r => r.Count - value1).ToList();
```

The point is that Select does not modify the list, it creates a new list

Comment: You can't assign ```HoList = HoList.Select(r => r.Count - value1).ToList();``` because you're trying to convert whatever type ```HoList``` is to a ```List<int>```. If ```HoList``` was a ```List<int>``` then yes but we know it isn't because he is using ```r.Count``` in the statement. Also ```Select``` doesn't create a list it mutates the enumeration as it's enumerated in this example (and differently with EF).. ```ToList()``` is what produces a new list with the result of that ```Select``` statement.